# Why my custom event fires twice?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I've searched relevant posts but I got nothing much

I have created a user control. In my user control there is a text box. I want to have an event in my user control that fires whenever text box `TextChanged` event raises. 
 This is what I have done so far : 
(This is code of user control)

```
public event EventHandler txtchnged;

    public void ontxtchnged()
    {
        txtchnged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        ontxtchnged();  
    }
```

Here is where I have used user control

```
    public RegisterMainFrm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        myUserControl1.txtchnged += myUserControl1_txtchnged;

    }

    private void myUserControl1_txtchnged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
```

This works and I know that the code might not be clean but that's not the problem. Problem is : "hello" will be printed in console twice and I really don't know why and how to fix it.

Comment: Your code looks fine so it looks like your textbox is changing twice.

Comment: Put breakpoint at `ontxtchnged();` line. Then inspect call stack to see why. If you want to get a complete answer - post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provided code will output one `"hello"` for a single change of `textBox1.Text`. Mistake (if there is any) somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps right click on myUserControl1_txtchnged and select find "Find All References". Could be another connection lurking somewhere.

Comment: @hungndv, not true. Whilst the code is bewildering (not least because of so many spellings of, and random uses of, text changed), if you trace the code you'll see it's too separate events that are subscribed to in the the two `+=` lines.

Comment: _the code might not be clean but that's not the problem_ - it is a problem for reading and maintaining the code as well as for answering this question.

Comment: What @HenkHolterman says: the fact that you have confused people here with the code shows there is a problem with the code. Clean it up and the cause of future problems will likely be far more obvious to you and everyone else.

Comment: @hungndv [I think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114923/why-my-custom-event-fires-twice/31115324?noredirect=1#comment50244542_31115324) your answer is/was correct. If you don't want to undelete it because it has been (IMO wrongly) already downvoted you may post a new one (maybe explanation was too short and people didn't understand it). Well, of course I may be wrong too...

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN on TextBox.TextChanged:

> Note:This event fires when the TextBox control is created and
>   initially populated with text.

Could this be your problem that you get the initial event?

UPDATE:
From Adriano Repetti Hint in Comments: Did you get the textBox1_TextChanged event handler by double clicking in the designer?
Then you have added a second hook to the TextChanged Event.

Check the code inside InitializeComponent of your UserControl if it is already hooking the event.

Comment: I think @hungndv was right, OP attached event handler twice. Note that TextBox is initialized inside InitializeComponent() and visible even handler is attached _after_. It'll be fired during initialization but his event handler isn't attached yet.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : I think he is wrong. The event of the textbox gets fired and triggers the usercontrol. Then the usercontrol fires ontxtchanged. This event is received by the mainform hosting the usercontrol hosting the textbox and writes the line. Or do I have a mistake here?

Comment: We don't have his full source code but: 1) Text property is first assigned 2)  TextChanged is fired but no event handlers then nothing will happens (note that myUserControl1_txtchnged is attached after InitializeComponents). 3) Event handler is attached. Also note that designer attaches event handlers after objects have been initialized.

Comment: However if there is an event handler attached in InitializeComponent() then 1) Text property is first assigned but nothing happens 2) designer generated code attaches first event handler 3) OP code attaches same event handler again 4) user changes text and event is generated once but received two times by the same function.

Comment: It may not be but also method signature is the Designer generated one (with private modifier) instead of the one generated by editor when you double TAB (of course it's not an evidence but a hint).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Good point. I added the possibility to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a check before accepting a subscription.

```
    private event EventHandler _txtchnged;
    public event EventHandler txtchnged{
     add{
      if(_txtchnged == null || !_txtchnged.GetInvocationList().Contains(value)){
        _txtchnged  += value;
      }
     }
     remove{
      _txtchnged  -= value;

     }
    }           

    public void ontxtchnged()
    {
        _txtchnged  (this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        ontxtchnged();  
    }
```